# oc get deployment is returning No resources found

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, command-line-interface, openshift

"***oc get deployment***" command is returning "**No resources Found**" as the result.

Even if I put an option of assigning or defining the namespace using -n as the option to above command, I am getting the same result.

Whereas, I am getting the correct result of ***oc get pods*** command.

Meanwhile, the oc version is
oc  - v3.6.0
kubernetes - v1.6.1

openshift - v3.11.380

Comment: How certain are you that a `deployment`, rather than a `deploymentconfig`, is being used?

Answer (score 1):

Check, if you connect to the correct kubernetes environment, (especially if you're running more than one).
If that is correct, I guess, either you don't have any deployments at all, or the deployments are in a different namespace than you think.
Try out listing all deployments:
oc get deployments -A

Answer (score 1):

There are other objects that create pods such as `statefulset` or `deamonset`. Because it is OpenShift, my feeling is that the pods created by a `deploymentconfig` which is popular way to create applications.

Anyway, you can make sure which object is the owner of the pods by looking into the pod annotation. This command should work:

```
oc get pod -o yaml <podname> | grep ownerReference -A 6
```